# Find date/time of last update to email address in Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap, adlds

When our users are changing their password in AD LDS, via a custom C# app, we also allow them to update their email address.  Is there a way to detect the date/time of when the email address was updated?  Or will we just have to use the LastPasswordSet value?  We need to compare it with the email in our AS/400 and sync them based on which address is most recent.

Comment: There is also an attribute `whenChanged` have you looked into that?

Comment: you can also use the event log https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=642

Answer (score 0):

You can get all history about account changes by watching `Windows Security Log Event ID 642` from active directory windows server.
([ref](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=642))

Answer (score 0):

The attribute metadata will tell you when the attribute was changed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.attributemetadata?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

I don't know of any way to *filter* on metadata, but I routinely filter on the whenChanged timestamp (or password updated timestamp in your case) to get a set of *potential* changes and filter out irrelevant objects using metadata for the attribute I'm tracking.

```
// Grab all accounts updated since last batch cycle
// For each user, check LastOriginatingChangeTime of interesting attribute
// If LastOriginatingChangeTime >= last cycle, check value in target system
// If value in target system != value in AD, update target system with value from AD
```